# Can't install anything on my router shell

Tags: linux, bash, router, shell, cron

I know this might be a noob question or maybe not. I have an ssh shell with my router and I want to make a cronjob for the router to update the IP address of a DDNS provider(Dynu.com). I tried the setting of the router which has that DDNS option. But for some reason it didn't work. Now what I am trying to do is this `wget "the update url"`. But, it don't has wget or curl either and when I tried to install it, there is no known pakage installers too. I tried `pkg,apt,yum,dnf,make` and many more. They don't work either. all they say is `-sh: pkg: not found`. I know this may be a stupid question. As I am extremely new to all these. Kindly help me with this. Also the `uname -a` output is this `Linux tc 2.6.36 #7 SMP Fri May 22 11:51:16 CST 2020 mips unknown`. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Provide some details on the router itself (like model) as not all routers have the same settings or procedures.  Also check to see if DYNU.COM has a updater utility (most respectable ddns services provide this.  If so use that on the router not the way you are trying to do it manually.

Comment: Depending on what distro runs on your router, you may have a package manager, or not. It's impossible to say unless you tell us what runs on your router. If the firmware is provided by the vendor/your ISP, it likely will not. If you don't have a package manager, install Firmware which does (e.g. OpenWRT), assuming it supports your router hardware.

Comment: @linuxdev2013 The modem is a RL821GWV from a brand called Optronix.

Comment: @dirkt `Linux version 2.6.36 (root@huolin-virtual-machine) (gcc version 4.3.6 (Buildroot 2012.05) ) #7 SMP Fri May 22 11:51:16 CST 2020` that is the output for `cat /proc/version`

Comment: That gives us the kernel version (and a pretty ancient one), but no clue as to what runs on it. "Optronix RL821GWV" means that it runs whatever Optronix put onto it, so likely you won't have a package manager. OpenWRT doesn't have entries for that, so unless it's a clone of something else, you are probably out of luck. If it was my router, the next thing I'd do is to start trying to find out what hardware it has - read `dmesg`, look for interesting binary/configuration files, etc.

Comment: @dirkt I tried everything. But gave up. Thank you all for your help.